# Separate implementation and declaration with templates and nested types in C++

Tags: c++, templates, nested, implementation

If I keep the function Find() inlined, then the program compiles. Otherwise, as shown below, it does not compile.

Is it possible to separate the declaration and implementation of such:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    struct MyStruct
    {
        int id;
        T value;
    };

    MyStruct *Find(int id);

private:
};

template<class T>
MyClass<T>::MyStruct *Find(int id)
{
    return nullptr;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyClass<int> c;

    c.Find(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to qualify your return value with [`typename`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) and the implementation needs to be qualified as a member of `MyClass`.

```
template<class T>
typename MyClass<T>::MyStruct * MyClass<T>::Find(int id)
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, [as long as you keep them in the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). If you try to separate the definition in a different source file, you'll most likely going to end up with linker errors (unless you provide explicit instantiations and use only the latter in your code).

You get a compile error because you need `typename` in

```
typename MyClass<T>::MyStruct
```

as the latter is a [dependent name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords/613132#613132).  In the inline case, the name `MyClass<T>` is injected and it is relative to the instantiation, so there is no need to explicitly specify the template parameter.

**EDIT** As @cocarin mentioned, you also need to qualify `MyClass<T>::Find(int id)`, since it is a member function of `MyClass<T>`. However, if you don't, the program will still compile but won't link. That's because you end up defining a global function `Find`, then try to invoke the member function, which ends up not being defined.

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
template<class T>
typename MyClass<T>::MyStruct * MyClass<T>::Find(int id)
{
    return nullptr;
}
```

or, since C++11

```
template<class T>
auto MyClass<T>::Find(int id)
-> MyStruct* /* no need of typename MyClass<T>:: here :) */
{
    return nullptr;
}
```